# Retrofit How to post data on specific field only?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

I want to post arraylist of object only specific field. I usually store all field object to post call.
I don't know where should I change.

Here is my object class

```
public class Verify {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private String phone;
}
```

The API only need to post ID as parameter, and there is multiple data in array.
For example :

```
List<Verify> ver = new Arraylist()<>;
ver.add("1", John, 62807677999);
ver.add("2", Dap, 6286753193);
ver.add("3", Keel, 62812386423);
ver.add("4", Martin, 62819823733);
```

API Service

```
@POST("https://www.mmsnusindo.com/api/ver/kunjungan/rejected")
    Call<List<Verify>> verifikasiKunjunganRejected(@Header("api-key") String content_type, @Body ArrayList<Verify> modelContact);
```

what error I get

```
{"status":false,"message":"Error data validation","info":{"id":["The id field is required."]}}
```

this code like verification data user, so there will be multiple data in arraylist, i pick data valid or not using checkbox and then send valid or not valid using POST API.

Example successful post Request
[image]

Comment: post the full url you want to call

Comment: or if you have postman so check it in postman and leave screenshots of postman here so the people can understand it better

Comment: i added success result example when posting invalid data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per screenshot. body is not required. So it can be like this

```
@POST("https://www.mmsnusindo.com/api/ver/kunjungan/rejected")
    Call<List<Verify>> verifikasiKunjunganRejected(@Header("api-key") String content_type,
                                                   @Query("id") String id;// please check your id is int or String.
```

Answer (score 0):

As in api url `?id=284213` is showing then you need to add `query` parameter into your call.

Try below code:

```
@POST("https://www.mmsnusindo.com/api/ver/kunjungan/rejected")
    Call<List<Verify>> verifikasiKunjunganRejected(@Header("api-key") String content_type,
                                                   @Query("id") String id,// please check your id is int or String.
                                                   @Body ArrayList<Verify> modelContact);
```